# How do I implement transitionCompleted of the UIPageViewController delegate in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

As you can see, there are two `UIViewControllers` (one of them is called `ProView` and acts as a container for the other `UIViewController` and one `UIPageViewController`.

[image: gif1]

```
import UIKit

class ProView: UIViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pageViewController: UIPageViewController?

let characterImages = ["character1", "character2"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createPageViewController()
    setupPageControl()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerAfterViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex+1 < characterImages.count {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex+1)
        }

        return nil
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController,
    viewControllerBeforeViewController ProView: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

    let itemController = ProView as PageItemController

        if itemController.itemIndex > 0 {
            return getItemController(itemController.itemIndex-1)
        }

        return nil
}

private func getItemController(itemIndex: Int) -> PageItemController? {

    if itemIndex < characterImages.count {
        let pageItemController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ItemController") as PageItemController
        pageItemController.itemIndex = itemIndex
        pageItemController.imageName = characterImages[itemIndex]
        return pageItemController
}

    return nil
}

func createPageViewController() {

    let pageController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PageController") as UIPageViewController
    pageController.dataSource = self

    if characterImages.count > 0 {
        let firstController = getItemController(0)!
        let startingViewControllers: NSArray = [firstController]
        pageController.setViewControllers(startingViewControllers, direction:     UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    pageViewController = pageController
    addChildViewController(pageViewController!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageViewController!.view)
    pageViewController?.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
}

func setupPageControl() {
    let appearance = UIPageControl.appearance()
    appearance.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    appearance.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return characterImages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}

}

class PageItemController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var imageCharacterChoose: UIImageView!

var itemIndex: Int = 0
var imageName: String = "" {
    didSet {

        if let imageView = imageCharacterChoose {imageCharacterChoose.image = UIImage(named: imageName)
        }

    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imageCharacterChoose!.image = UIImage(named: imageName)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

I would like to know if the user correctly swipes from one view to another. For that matter, I need the method `transitionCompleted` to work:

```
func pageViewController(ProView: UIPageViewController,
    didFinishAnimating finished: Bool,
    previousViewControllers pageViewController: [AnyObject],
    transitionCompleted completed: Bool)
{
// If the page did not turn
if (!completed)
{
// You do nothing because whatever page you thought
// the book was on before the gesture started is still the correct page
println("The page number did not change.")
return;
}

// This is where you would know the page number changed and handle it appropriately
println("The page number has changed.")
}
```

The problem is that doesn't work (the console output doesn't print anything) because the parameters aren't correct probably. According to Apple Reference,

**pageViewController** The page view controller.
**previousViewControllers** The view controllers prior to the transition.

I therefore changed the parameters using "ProView" and "pageViewController" but that doesn't seem to work. **What are the correct parameters according to the code for the `transitionCompleted` method?** Do I need to declare something?

Comment: "that doesn't work" What does that mean? What does happen?

Comment: `pageViewController(ProView: UIPageViewController` Do not use a class name as a parameter name! That's horrible.

Comment: Woops! Thanks for the tip Matt, as always.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:...` is a delegate method, but this class is not the page view controller's delegate.

You have this line:

```
pageController.dataSource = self
```

So you are setting the `dataSource`. But you never set the `delegate`. Set it:

```
pageController.delegate = self
```

Comment: It's always something simple, isn't it? :)

Comment: Where did you know/read/learn this `delegate` thing? I have searched everywhere for an answer but I never found it.

Comment: The method is defined in the UIPageViewControllerDelegate docs. That's a protocol. Now look in the UIPageViewController docs. It has a `delegate` property which _is_ a UIPageViewControllerDelegate. So that is how you set up the relationship between them. This is a _very_ common Cocoa pattern.